# Scheduling a Task using Alarm Manager in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want to show stale bar notification when the app is in the background. I used AlarmManager to to implement the task. But I want to repeat AlarmManager for a 1 min for three times, ie I wanted to show stale bar notification when the app is in background for 1 min interval for three times. I saw `setRepeating` method of AlarmManager which allows you to repeat at 1 Min intervel. Can any one help me with this?